# No relaciona tablas mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

Alguien me podria colaborar en relacionar tablas en mysql de versión Workbench, he revisado y por lo que veo esta bien pero al momento de aplicar ingenieria inversa no muestra que esta relacionado. Este es:

```
create database granja;
use granja;
CREATE TABLE ANIMAL(
    ID INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NOMBRE TEXT(20) NOT NULL,
    EDAD INT(2),
    RAZA VARCHAR(20),
    PRECIO INT(7),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
    );


CREATE TABLE vacunas(
    ID INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NOMBRE TEXT(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    ID_ANIMAL INT(6),
    INDEX(ID_ANIMAL),
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_ANIMAL)references 
    ANIMAL(ID)
    );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que tal miguel, tal vez el problema sea al momento de visualizar el diagrama... Verifica si está correctamente relacionado desde la consola con un `describe vacunas`

Comment: Reproduje tu código, pero no encuentro ningun problema... Tal vez sea problema de tu diseñador en Workbench. verifica con el comando que dije mas arriba

Comment: Revisa que las tablas sean `InnoDB`, si son `MyISAM` las relaciones no serán reconocidas.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo logre solucionar, no sé cual seria el error. Lo desinstalé e instalé el paquete de Mysql server Community y elimine las conexiones que tenia y listo.